# fastcgi_mono_server 4 wildcard hostname

Tags: nginx, mono

I have configured nginx with fastcgi_mono_server4.
In my nginx config I have 2 hostnames :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  dev.example.org
    location / {
             root /var/www/dev.example.org/;
             fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
             fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
             include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
}

 server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  *.example.org
        location / {
             root /var/www/example.org/;
             fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
             fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
             include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

nginx is OK with this configuration. dev goes to one and all other to another one .

I've already tried this :

```
fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=*.example.org:/:/var/www/example.org/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000
```

but it throws an error (Uri parse exception)

**Update :**
I need to get the full host name in my application, for example if the request was abc.example.org, I need to get "abc".
Unfortunately, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url does not contains "abc" but "*" which causes the parse error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nginx is going to take care of routing the appropriate sub-domains to each fastcgi port (9000 or 9001) then can you get away with a wildcard domain when you start the mono server process e.g. just use a * instead of '*.example.org'

```
fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=*:/:/var/www/example.org/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000
```

**Update:** The above works to get two Mono server apps listening via nginx, but, using the nginx config from the original question will lead to an exception if you call `HttpContext.Request.Url` on the catch-all server. This is due to it not liking the `*` in `*.example.org`.

There are two possible solutions, depending what you'd like to see returned from `HttpContext.Request.Url` when a client browses `foo.example.org`, `bar.example.org` etc.

**Option 1:** If you don't care about the sub-domain and want to see `example.org`

Configure the second (`*.example.org`) nginx server to be the 'default_server' and have it assign a server-name without the wildcard e.g.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name example.org;
  access_log ... }
```

With these settings, browsing to `foo.example.org/Default.aspx` loads the page and `HttpContext.Request.Url` returns `example.org/Default.aspx`

**Option 2:** If you want to see the actual sub-domain e.g. `foo.example.org`

Removing the server_name from the second server definition works.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  access_log ... }
```

With these settings, browsing to `foo.example.org/Default.aspx` loads the page and `HttpContext.Request.Url` returns `foo.example.org/Default.aspx`

Comment: I've just tested you answer. In my case it does not work, because in my conf, there is 2 server one listening to dev.example.org and one for all other (*.example.org). If i don't set the server name for the second definition nginx throws 502.

Answer (score 0):

*@stephen's answer is more simple and does not need fastcgi config modification.*

I tried previous answer (before update), but it did not work.
Nginx take care of routing, as @stephen said, and the routing part worked.

to start fastcgi I used this command to match all routes (and server names)

```
fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=/:/var/www/example.org/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000
```

The problem was that HttpContext.Request.Url contains the $server_name value in my case it was "*.example.org" and when I try to parse URI there was an error.

To handle this I changed nginx fastcgi_params and replaced thi line

```
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

by

```
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $http_host;
```

and add in site-available conf

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

I think it is set by default.

reload nginx

```
nginx -t && service nginx reload
```

reload fastcgi-mono-server to test

```
 fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=/://var/www/example.org/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 /printlog=True /loglevels=Debug
```

in the log SERVER_NAME contains the real (not *) subomain.

Comment: Do you need to know the exact sub-domain being used or are you just looking for a way to prevent 'HttpContext.Request.Url' from throwing an exception?

If the latter then, you can configure the second (*.example.org) nginx server to be the 'default_server' and have it assign a server-name without the wildcard e.g. 'example.org'. With these settings, browsing to 'http://foo.example.org/Default.aspx' loads the page and HttpContext.Request.Url returns 'http://example.org/Default.aspx'
EXAMPLE:
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.org;
    access_log ...
    }

Comment: Additionally to my comment above, if you do want the exact sub-domain passed then I have found that removing the server_name from the second server definition works. With these settings, browsing to 'foo.example.org/Default.aspx'; loads the page and HttpContext.Request.Url returns 'foo.example.org/Default.aspx'; EXAMPLE: server { listen 80 default_server; access_log ... }

Comment: Can you edit your answer so i can set it as answer ?

Comment: Done - that is a nicer place to put the details than in a comment! :-)